# Calling method from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem calling a method from my view `switches/index.slim`:

```
=link_to 'Switch 1', switch_toggle_path, class: 'button'
```

and the corresponding route:

```
get '/switches', to: 'switches#relay_toggle', as: 'switch_toggle'
```

and the controller:

```
class SwitchesController < ApplicationController

  include PiPiper
  before_action :init_pins

  def init_pins
    @relay1 = PiPiper::Pin.new(:pin => 18, :direction => :out)
    @relay2 = PiPiper::Pin.new(:pin => 27, :direction => :out)
  end

  def relay_toggle
    @relay1.read == 0 ? @relay1.update_value(1) : @relay1.update_value(0)
    redirect_to '/'
  end
end
```

I only need to instantiate the pins once, but obviously I'm doing this every time i call, `relay_toggle` now. How can I make sure that they only get instantiated once? 
Can I put them somewhere that gets, loaded with the application? And if I did that, how would I then reference the @relay objects in the controller?

Also, should i make use of the helpers instead of declaring this in the controller? If so, how? I'm a bit out of clue as to what to do.

So any help or direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You could put them in an initializer but I'd advise against it. You should have a swtiches_helper class if you used a rails generator. You can place the method in here.

If you don't have a helper file create one in `app/helpers/switches_helper.rb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Controller**

When you mentioned you didn't know whether your method should be stored in the controller or a helper, you need to appreciate the role of the MVC programming pattern in Rails:

[image]

The way Rails works (and remember, *Rails* is based on top of *Ruby* -- [it's a gem](https://github.com/rails/rails) in actuality), which means that if you want to use a particular method / file in your system, it has to adhere to the MVC programming pattern as detailed above.

--

So the answer to the question of whether you should use a `controller method` or a helper, you'd use a `helper` *if* it was intended to be loaded *after* your view. Controller methods collate the relative data from your `Model` - allowing you to display it in the view:

```
Request -> Router -> Controller/Action -> View -> Helper
```

This is the way in which your controller sets up the item

--

**Initializers**

> **Can I put them somewhere that gets, loaded with the application?**

You may put them in an [*initializer*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html) -

```
#config/initializers/your_initializer.rb
RELAY_ONE = PiPiper::Pin.new(:pin => 18, :direction => :out)
RELAY_TWO = PiPiper::Pin.new(:pin => 27, :direction => :out)
```

If you use the code above, it will create two [*constants*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(computer_programming)) which will allow you to call them throughout the application (them having been already initialized)

If you do the above, it will give you the ability to remove the declarations from your controller, and just use the constants instead (considering, of course, that you only want the two objects to be defined):

```
#app/controllers/switches_controller.rb
class SwitchesController < ApplicationController
  def relay_toggle
    RELAY_ONE.read == 0 ? RELAY_ONE.update_value(1) : RELAY_ONE.update_value(0)
    redirect_to '/'
  end
end
```

Comment: Rich, thank you once again for a very elaborate answer. This really helped me out!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Class variable

```
class SwitchesController < ApplicationController

  include PiPiper
  @@relay1 = PiPiper::Pin.new(:pin => 18, :direction => :out)
  @@relay2 = PiPiper::Pin.new(:pin => 27, :direction => :out)

  def relay_toggle
    @@relay1.read == 0 ? @@relay1.update_value(1) : @@relay1.update_value(0)
    redirect_to '/'
  end
end
```

But i'm not sure that's what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can init it once on server start and app init, just add initializer and declare constants

```
# config/initializers/relay.rb
RelayOne = PiPiper::Pin.new(:pin => 18, :direction => :out)
RelayTwo = PiPiper::Pin.new(:pin => 27, :direction => :out)

# controller

def relay_toggle
  RelayOne.read == 0 ? RelayOne.update_value(1) : RelayOne.update_value(0)
  redirect_to '/'
end
```